# My device id for AdMob Testing changed (Android)

Tags: android, admob

I have set the device id of the phone I use for adMob testing as a const in my app. My testing device is not my day-to-day device.

Today I wanted to test a use case with a reward video and all of the sudden I get `no fill` or `internal errors`.

I took a look into the Log Cat and I saw that the *device Id changed*

By device Id I am referring to the one that comes in this log:

```
I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("THIS_ID_HERE") to get test ads on this device.
```

- Why does it changed?
- Is it because I uninstalled the prod version and installed a dev version of my app?
- Does it happens randomly?
- Can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Device Id changes if you reset your phone. It may cause when you update your OS.
It does not change randomly.
Uninstalling prod version and installing a dev version should not change your device id(AFAIK).

Comment: So there is no way to keep an "always valid" array of `testDevicesIds`?

Answer (score 0):

[As per google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units) given try to use below credential for testing ads.In that case you will **not need to add Device Id**.

```
<!--Ad test credentials-->
<string name="admob_app_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
<string name="banner_home_footer">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="interstitial_full_screen">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
<string name="rewarded_video">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917</string>

<!--Ad live credentials-->
<string name="admob_app_id">add here your live app id</string>
<string name="banner_home_footer">add here your live footer id</string>
<string name="interstitial_full_screen">add here your live interstitial id</string>
<string name="rewarded_video">add here your live rewarded id</string>
```

Now use below function for shows testing ads.

```
//Banner Ads
private void loadBannerAds(AdView mAdView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

//Interstitial Ads
private void loadInterstitialAds(final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//RewardedVideo Ads
private void loadRewardedVideoAd(RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(context.getResources().getString(R.string.rewarded_video), adRequest);

    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            try {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        }
    });

    // showing the ad to user
    // make sure the ad is loaded completely before showing it
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: The problem with this is that I can not test it with the correct response of different rewardVideos. I have to test always the same one that comes from google.

Comment: @distante Are you add setRewardedVideoAdListener? I have added in my updated answer.